# Get all entries with included images using Contentful REST API

Tags: contentful, contentful-management

I am using typescript,and the Contentful-ManagementAPI (that's the reason I'm not using the SDK client), and I want to retrieve all entries from a specific type. I am calling th Api like this:
`axios.get("https://api.contentful.com/spaces/" +
        space_id +
        "/entries?content_type=" +
        content_type+"&include="+2)`

I am receiving all the entries requested, but in the image field I am getting this:

`poster:en-US:
sys:
{type: "Link", linkType: "Asset", id: "222xxm9aaAu4GiAc2ESw0Q"}`

So, How could I get the image URL?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Contentful docs:

> The CMA does not support the include and locale parameters.

So, I might be better using the delivery api for retrieve content, and the management api for create/update/delete. That's the way it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced assets and entries can be found in the `includes` object in the API response.

The response should look something like this:

```
{
   "sys": {
       "type": "Array"
   },
  "total": 9,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [ // Your items here ],
  "includes": {
      "Asset": [ // Your included assets here, this is where you find the url to the image ]
      "Entry": [ // Any referenced entries not included in the items array above ]
  }
```

So to find the actual asset that includes all your data (including the url) you would have to find the correct asset, using the id of the reference (222xxm9aaAu4GiAc2ESw0Q), in the `includes.Asset` object.

Comment: I can't seem to find the includes array in my response

Comment: It's on the same level as the items array. How do you read the response?

Comment: I loop over `response.data`

Comment: See the response by Oscar Cabrera Rodriguez. You are calling the Content Management API which does not include references. I missed that. If you are only reading content you should consider using the delivery api (cdn.contentful.com instead of api.contentful.com), which does include references. Otherwise the only option is to make a separate call to fetch the asset for which you want a URL by id.

Comment: Turns out I've answered my own question :). Anyway, thxs for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try include=10, If you are using multi locales provide fallback for each locale.
This worked for me.